# suppressing / omiting repetitive logs in nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging

I am looking into Winston, Morgan and alike but I couldnT find anything that can convert this :

```
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection
```

into sth like this:

```
[NOTIFICATION] - inserting an item in the collection x 12
```

as in Chrome dev tools console for example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could throttle the logging call, underscore has a [throttling](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) function:

```
var writeLog = _.throttle(function(message) {
    log.info(message);
}, 3000); // Throttled to once every 3 seconds

setInterval(function() {
    writeLog(new Date().toTimeString());
}, 1000);
```

You would expect a log message to be written every second, but the throttle results in one message every 3 seconds